# Does the Magus' Spell-strike work on both melee and ranged touch spells?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magus

Does the Magus' [Spell-strike](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/magus/) work on both melee and ranged touch spells?

> whenever a magus casts a spell with a range of ***“touch”*** from the magus spell list, he can deliver the spell through any weapon he is wielding as part of a melee attack.

So does mean that this only function with spells like Shocking Grasp and not with Scorching Ray; or both?

Answer (score 6):

“Touch” spells are melee, and “ranged touch” spells are ranged. The rules rarely specify “melee touch” and from context it is very clear that “touch” implies melee unless it’s explicitly “ranged touch.” Consider the definition of the “Touch” range from the magic overview:

> ### Range
>
> [...]
>
> - #### Touch
>
>   You must touch a creature or object to affect it. **A touch spell** that deals damage can score a critical hit just as a weapon can. **A touch spell** threatens a critical hit on a natural roll of 20 and deals double damage on a successful critical hit. Some **touch spells** allow you to touch multiple targets. You can touch up to 6 willing targets as part of the casting, but all targets of the spell must be touched in the same round that you finish casting the spell. If the spell allows you to touch targets over multiple rounds, touching 6 creatures is a full-round action.

<sup>([Magic Overview → Range](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/Magic/#Range), **emphasis** mine)</sup>

Here we can clearly see that “spells with range: touch” are called “touch spells.” The term “touch spell” does **not** include spells with ranges beyond touch, even if they include one or more touch attack rolls. Those are “ranged touch spells,” and are separate.

When the rules want to refer to all spells that include touch attack rolls, they generally say “touch and ranged touch” to be clear they mean both.

So spellstrike works with *shocking grasp*, and not with *scorching ray*. See the ranged spellstrike feature of the eldritch archer archetype for an option that does work with *scorching ray* (and as confirmation that you need to modify spellstrike to cover ranged touch attacks).

Answer (score 5):

#### Spell-Strike does *not* work with ranged touch attacks.

From the [PFSRD](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/scorching-ray/):

> **Scorching Ray**
> ...
> *Range:* close (25 ft. + 5 ft./2 levels)
> ...

Spell-strike applies to spells with a range of touch. Ranged touch spells, such as Scorching Ray, have a range of close, medium, or long. Therefore Spell-strike does not apply.

If Spell-strike's text said it applied to touch attacks, *then* it would work with Scorching Ray and other ranged touch attacks, but instead it specifies spells with a range of touch.

Answer (score 4):

The magus' spellstrike functions only for spells explicitly with a range of touch. A spell's Range is listed in its block (above the "Target" entry). For spells that are melee touch spells, that entry reads "touch". For spells that are ranged touch spells, that entry reads "close" "medium" or "long".

In order to use ranged touch spells with Spellstrike, you must have some feature or feat that allows it. For example, the following two archetypes allow it:

> **[Myrmidarch Magus Archetype](https://aonprd.com/ArchetypeDisplay.aspx?FixedName=Magus%20Myrmidarch), Ranged Spellstrike:** At 4th level, a myrmidarch can use spellstrike to cast a single-target touch attack ranged spell and deliver it through a ranged weapon attack. Even if the spell can normally affect multiple targets, only a single missile, ray, or effect accompanies the attack. (...)

> **[Eldritch Archer Magus Archetype](https://aonprd.com/ArchetypeDisplay.aspx?FixedName=Magus%20Eldritch%20Archer), Ranged Spellstrike:** At 2nd level, whenever an eldritch archer casts a spell that calls for a ranged attack, she can deliver the spell through a ranged weapon she wields as part of a ranged attack. Instead of the free ranged attack normally allowed to deliver the spell, an eldritch archer can make one free ranged attack with a ranged weapon (at her highest base attack bonus) as part of casting this spell. The attack does not increase the spell’s range. (...)